# How to Create Button in in multiple row and column in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am stuck in this position from last 3 days. I am unable to find out how to solve this. I have multiple data in a array. According to data I have to create a route in my Application. I am creating the button in a for loop. but its coming one row by row. But my requirement is like, in every row it should be a opposite direction.

This is my requirement.

[image]

This purple color is my buttons, and red colors are path.

```
int x_pos = 40;
int y_pos = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i ++)
{
    UIButton *courseBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    courseBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x_pos, y_pos, 40, 40);
    courseBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.courseMapScroll addSubview:courseBtn];

    courseBtn.layer.cornerRadius = courseBtn.frame.size.height/2;
    courseBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    NSLog(@"x_pos == %d",x_pos);
    x_pos = x_pos + (SCREEN_WIDTH - 120);

    if (x_pos > 320)
    {
        x_pos = 40;
        y_pos = y_pos + 100;
    }
    [self.courseMapScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, y_pos + 70)];
}
```

My code is like this

Please anybody can help me. Please

Thanks alots

Comment: one way I may try is to create the button and path view, then assign calculated frame for them programmatically and using addSubView method to place the views into their parent view. This is a bit tedious though.

Comment: are you using tableview ?or it is normal view

Comment: i am using a scrollview on scrollview i m adding button

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you're using?

Comment: I updated my question. Plz check

Comment: @SRNayak I added an answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, exactly how you asked for it (with the green line that you requested in chat). Have fun tweaking the values :)

```
int numButtons = 6;
int yInterval = 100;
int leftX = 50;
int rightX = self.view.frame.size.width - leftX*2;
int lineWidth = 6;
int buttonRadius = 40;
int topMargin = 60;   

for (float i = 1; i < numButtons+1 ; i++) {
    float yPos = (ceil(i/2)-1)*yInterval+topMargin;
    BOOL isRightDirection = (fmod(ceil(i/2),2) == 1);
    BOOL isEven = (fmod(i,2) == 0);
    BOOL isOnLeft = (isRightDirection != isEven);
    float xPos = (isOnLeft) ? leftX : rightX;

    if (i != numButtons) {
        double nextUnlockedDecimal = (double)nextPercentUnlocked/100;
        UIView *redLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        redLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        UIView *greenLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        greenLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        if (isEven) {
            //Vertical
            int xToUse = (isRightDirection) ? rightX : leftX;
            redLine.frame = CGRectMake(xToUse + buttonRadius/2 - lineWidth/2, yPos + buttonRadius/2, lineWidth, yInterval);
            if (i == latestUnlocked) {
                greenLine.frame = CGRectMake(xToUse + buttonRadius/2 - lineWidth/2, yPos + buttonRadius/2, lineWidth, nextUnlockedDecimal * yInterval);
            } else if (i < latestUnlocked) {
                greenLine.frame = redLine.frame;
            }
        } else {
            //Horizontal
            redLine.frame = CGRectMake(leftX + buttonRadius/2, yPos + buttonRadius/2 - lineWidth/2, rightX-leftX, lineWidth);
            if (i == latestUnlocked) {
                double greenLineX = (isRightDirection) ? leftX + buttonRadius/2 : rightX + buttonRadius/2 - nextUnlockedDecimal * (rightX-leftX);
                greenLine.frame = CGRectMake(greenLineX, yPos + buttonRadius/2 - lineWidth/2, nextUnlockedDecimal * (rightX-leftX), lineWidth);
            } else if (i < latestUnlocked) {
                greenLine.frame = redLine.frame;
            }
        }

        greenLine.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5;
        [self.view addSubview:redLine];
        [self.view addSubview:greenLine];
    }

    UIButton *courseBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    courseBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    courseBtn.layer.cornerRadius = buttonRadius/2;
    courseBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    courseBtn.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 40, 40);
    NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(int)i];
    [courseBtn setTitle:numStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.courseMapScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, yPos + 70)];
    [self.courseMapScroll addSubview:courseBtn];
}
```

Comment: Yes, its working fine, but how to create that path, please tell me :)

Comment: @SRNayak I added the lines as well. Good luck with your app!

Comment: Great dude. Thanks a lots alots alots.....one issue is there . If i took numButtons == 5 (any odd no) one extra red line addes in last number button.

Comment: @SRNayak ok. I fixed that too. Check my updated post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96430/discussion-between-s-r-nayak-and-kabiroberai).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I really did that... This should work, I haven't tested it though... I would recommend you to use a global mutable array (courseButtons) to store the buttons so you can check on the target their index against the array and know which one was clicked.

```
CGFloat buttonHorizontalMargin=40;
CGFloat buttonVerticalMargin=50;
CGFloat buttonSize=40;

CGFloat x_pos = buttonHorizontalMargin;
CGFloat y_pos = buttonVerticalMargin;

[self.courseMapScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.courseMapScroll.bounds.size.width, y_pos + buttonSize+buttonVerticalMargin*0.5)];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [_buttonPoints count] ; i ++)
{
    UIButton *courseBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [courseBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [courseBtn setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    [courseBtn setAutoresizesSubviews:(((i+1)%2==0&&(i+1)%4!=0)||(i+1)%3==0)?UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin:UIViewAutoresizingRightMargin];
    [courseBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    courseBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x_pos, y_pos, buttonSize, buttonSize);
    courseBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.courseButtons addObject:courseBtn];
    [self.courseMapScroll addSubview:courseBtn];

    courseBtn.layer.cornerRadius = courseBtn.frame.size.height*0.5;
    courseBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    NSLog(@"x_pos == %d",x_pos);
    if((i+1)%4){
        x_pos = buttonHorizontalMargin;
    }else if((i+1)%3||(i+1)%2){
        x_pos = self.courseMapScroll.bounds.size.width-buttonHorizontalMargin-buttonSize;
    }else{
        x_pos = buttonHorizontalMargin;
    }

    if (i>0 && i%2==0){
        y_pos = y_pos + buttonSize+buttonVerticalMargin;
        [self.courseMapScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.courseMapScroll.bounds.size.width, y_pos + buttonSize+buttonVerticalMargin*0.5)];
    }
}
```